# Slim3 Twig2 Blank Page - OVH server

Tags: php, slim

I have a blank page when using Slim3 + Twig2 + PHP 7.2 when I run the application on production (OVH server).
I'have been looking for any answer to my problem, but none of what I have found corrected it...

---

Thanks for your answer.

Here is my code in one of my controller :

```
function getAccueil($request, $response, $args = array(NULL))
{

    if (empty($args))
    {
        $args['lang'] = 'fr';
    }

    $lang = $args['lang'];
    $fr_url = '/fr.html';
    $en_url = '/en.html';

    return  $this->view->render($response, 'accueil.twig',  array(
        'lang' => $args['lang'],
        'fr_url' => $fr_url,
        'en_url' => $en_url,
    ));
}
```

I'm using php 7.2 (and already tried with previous versions)
and get a 200 return http code (using Chrome/Devlopment tools/Network)

Comment: See [ask] and take the [tour]. [Edit] the question and show your [mcve] and describe the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing killing the script with `die()`; before returning the twig renderer. If it still gives a blank page maybe check if something is wrong  in the php file where you define your `$app` and `$container`. Hope that you can do something with this answer.